# regex match but no comment

Tags: python, regex

Given file:

```
1.29.7D59                       ; This field should not be edited
SE5C620.86B.00.01   ; This field should not be edited
I/O Sensitive               ;Options: Balanced=00: I/O Sensitive=02
POR - Reg. Value:0x1F                 ;Options: 0.0%=00: 0.1%=01
```

To Do:

```
1.29.7D59
SE5C620.86B.00.01
I/O Sensitive
POR - Reg. Value:0x1F
```

Thus I need to extract `1.29.7D59`, `SE5C620.86B.00.01` etc.
Try is

```
\s*;+
```

But it is not working maybe I need to carry ahead look. New to regex so do not.

Please help

Comment: `\s*;+` only matches 0+ whitespace chars and then 1+ `;` chars. If you split separate lines with the pattern, then grab the first item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\s*;+` only matches 0+ whitespace chars and then 1+ `;` chars. If you split separate lines with the pattern, then grab the first item:

```
import re
s='''1.29.7D59                       ; This field should not be edited
SE5C620.86B.00.01   ; This field should not be edited
I/O Sensitive               ;Options: Balanced=00: I/O Sensitive=02
POR - Reg. Value:0x1F                 ;Options: 0.0%=00: 0.1%=01'''
lines = s.split('\n')
res = []
for line in lines:
    res.append(re.split(r'\s*;', line)[0])
print(res)
# => ['1.29.7D59', 'SE5C620.86B.00.01', 'I/O Sensitive', 'POR - Reg. Value:0x1F']
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/EdVC4p).

Alternatively, you may use the following regex:

```
^[^;]*[^\s;]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kLYBjr/1). If you read the file as one string, you might want to use it with a `re.MULTILINE` flag, or as `(?m)^[^;]*[^\s;]`.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string (or line if `re.M` flag is specified)
- `[^;]*` - 0+ chars other than `;`
- `[^\s;]` - a char other than whitespace and `;`.

See the [Python online demo](https://ideone.com/cI4kpB):

```
import re
s='''1.29.7D59                       ; This field should not be edited
SE5C620.86B.00.01   ; This field should not be edited
I/O Sensitive               ;Options: Balanced=00: I/O Sensitive=02
POR - Reg. Value:0x1F                 ;Options: 0.0%=00: 0.1%=01'''
print(re.findall(r'^[^;]*[^\s;]', s, re.M))
# => ['1.29.7D59', 'SE5C620.86B.00.01', 'I/O Sensitive', 'POR - Reg. Value:0x1F']
```

Comment: Works! You are awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.split`:

```
import re
s = """
1.29.7D59                       ; This field should not be edited
SE5C620.86B.00.01   ; This field should not be edited
I/O Sensitive               ;Options: Balanced=00: I/O Sensitive=02
POR - Reg. Value:0x1F                 ;Options: 0.0%=00: 0.1%=01
"""
final_data = '\n'.join([a for a, _ in [re.split('\s+(?=;)', i) for i in filter(None, s.split('\n'))]])
```

Output:

```
1.29.7D59
SE5C620.86B.00.01
I/O Sensitive
POR - Reg. Value:0x1F
```